# Downloading multiple jpegs into an array from urls in a data frame

Tags: r, image, for-loop, jpeg

Like the title says, I want to download multiple jpegs into an array from their url in a dataframe. The code I now have is as follows:

```
# for loop for train set
for (i in 1:274) { 
  theurl <- paste(train[i,c("Icon.URL")], sep = "")
  z <- tempfile()
  download.file(theurl,z,mode = "wb") #Download to the directory
  train_image <- readJPEG(z)
  writeJPEG(train_image, paste("imageTrain", i, ".jpg", sep = ""))
  file.remove(z) 
}
```

The 'train_image' is now a large array, with 786432 elements. This means that ultimately, only one of the jpegs is downloaded into that file, as each jpeg's dimensions are 512 x 512 x 3 = 786432. What is going wrong in the code that it seems to overwrite itself each time the for loop runs?

Additional information:

- 'train' is the data frame containing the urls
- I got this code from here:
  https://community.rstudio.com/t/access-and-download-images-from-urls-which-are-values-of-a-variable/66534 and
  https://community.rstudio.com/t/access-and-download-images-from-urls/94422

I have also tried to use append() in the following way:

```
for (i in 1:10) { 
  theurl <- paste(train[i,c("Icon.URL")], sep = "")
  z <- tempfile()
  download.file(theurl,z,mode = "wb") #Download to the directory
  train_img <- readJPEG(z)
  train_image <- append(train_image, train_img)
  writeJPEG(train_img, paste("imageTrain", i, ".jpg", sep = ""))
  file.remove(z) 
}
```

In this way, the images are added to 'train_image', but the results is a large numeric vector instead of an array

Comment: Is your train_image the image from train[274, "Icon.URL"]? If so, then it is because the loop overwrite the train_image for each i.

Comment: Yes it is. A friend of mine used the same code however and seemed to get an array with dimensions (274, 512, 512, 3), meaning all the jpegs got saved into the array. Do you have any idea how I could rewrite the for-loop to not overwrite itself?

Comment: How would you want all 274 image date to be kept as? You can keep it as separate objects in your R environment using `assign`, or you can keep it in a list. If you can share an example image of your data, I may help you with your second question on the array.

Comment: I would like all the images to be stored as a large array, which is how the for-loop now stores the one picture that is kept. An example image from the data is for instance this one: https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple113/v4/eb/d7/fb/ebd7fb8b-29e8-3ef4-7af0-e585891ffc04/source/512x512bb.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

We can create an array with the desired dimensions and use an additional dimension for the picture number.

```
#Example list of urls
urllist <- rep("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Apollonian_spheres.jpg", 10)

#create array with desired dimensions (pics here are 492x492x3). Include length of urllist as dimension

#create array with desired dimension
arrays <- array(dim = c(492, 492, 3, length(urllist)))

#loop through urllist and assign to array
for(i in 1:length(urllist)){
  #download
  z <- tempfile()
  download.file(myurl,z,mode="wb")
  
  #read
  pic <- readJPEG(z)
  
  #add to array.list
  arrays[,,,i] <- pic
}
```